# javascript 1.6 load local xml

Tags: javascript, xml

In javascript 1.6, is there a recommended process for loading local XML? It's not for a browser, so should lmllload work?

Comment: Is your problem accessing a local file or parsing its contents? Or perhaps both?

Comment: You failed to describe what context your JavaScript code **will** run in, if it's not a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript in a browser does not have access to the local file system, however, if you're planning to do some javascript programming on a desktop, I would recommend trying node js http://nodejs.org/ which is built on top of the V8 javascript engine used by chrome.